# Build failing to include com.fasterxml.jackson.core

Tags: scala, maven, apache-spark, jackson-databind

I am working on a build file utilizing dependencies from scala and spark packages, etc, on Java 1.8 and Scala 2.10.5. 
The build is throwing up on the jackson-bind package. I have added the entire pom and the exception I see:
**Exception**

central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2, releases=true, snapshots=false)

> [ERROR] : ClientProtocolException: 
>       Invalid redirect URI: http://blog.goodstuff.im/repo-releases/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-databind/[2.7.0,)/jackson-databind-[2.7.0,).jar:
>
> ```
> Illegal character in path at index 83: http://blog.goodstuff.im/repo-releases/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-databind/[2.7.0,)/jackson-databind-[2.7.0,).jar
> ```

**Tried the exclusion tags, it is still failing with an error:**

> ClientProtocolException: Invalid redirect URI:
>   http://blog.goodstuff.im/repo-releases/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-databind/[2.7.0,)/jackson-databind-[2.7.0,).jar:
>   Illegal character in path at index 83:
>   http://blog.goodstuff.im/repo-releases/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-databind/[2.7.0,)/jackson-databind-[2.7.0,).jar
>           [ERROR] -> [Help 1]
>           [ERROR] 
>           [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
>           [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
>           [ERROR] 
>           [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
>           [ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException

My pom.xml file:

```html
  
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
    <artifactId>c-platform</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>${project.version} - ${project.artifactId}</name>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <parent>     <groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
        <artifactId>c-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <relativePath>../pom.xml</relativePath>
    </parent>

    <repositories>

        <repository>
            <id>Nexus</id>
            <url>…-snapshots/</url>
            <releases>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </releases>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
        <repository>
             <id> Nexus shapshot</id>
             <url>../nexus/content/groups/public</url>
             <releases>
                 <enabled>true</enabled>
             </releases>
             <snapshots>
                 <enabled>true</enabled>
             </snapshots>
         </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>Cloudera</id>
            <url>https://repository.cloudera.com/artifactory/cloudera-repos</url>
            <releases>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </releases>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>

        <repository>
            <id>scala-tools.org</id>
            <name>Scala-tools Maven2 Repository</name>
            <url>http://scala-tools.org/repo-releases</url>
        </repository>

        <repository>
            <id>maven2-repository.dev.java.net</id>
            <name>Java.net Repository for Maven</name>
            <url>http://download.java.net/maven/2/</url>
            <layout>default</layout>
        </repository>

    </repositories>


    <!-- list all dependencies - begin -->

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
            <version>${scala.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.maxmind.geoip2</groupId>
            <artifactId>geoip2</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.databricks</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-csv_2.10</artifactId>
            <version>${spark.csv.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-core_2.10</artifactId>
            <version>${spark.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-sql_2.10</artifactId>
            <version>${spark.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-mllib_2.10</artifactId>
            <version>${spark.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-hive_2.10</artifactId>
            <version>${spark.version}</version>
        </dependency>
       <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.module</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-module-scala_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.3</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
                    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
                    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <!-- list all dependencies - emd -->
    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>src/main/scala</sourceDirectory>
        <testSourceDirectory>src/test/scala</testSourceDirectory>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <relocations>
                                <relocation>
                                    <pattern>com.fasterxml.jackson.**</pattern>
                                    <shadedPattern>com.shaded.fasterxml.jackson@1</shadedPattern>
                                </relocation>
                            </relocations>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.scala-tools</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-scala-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.10</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <args>
                                <arg>-dependencyfile</arg>
                                <arg>${project.build.directory}/.scala_dependencies</arg>
                            </args>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.7.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                    <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>
                    <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that jackson-databind 2.7.3 brings as transitive dependencies jackson-annotations and jackson-core 2.7.0 which might cause some dependency conflict in your build.
I couldn't reproduce exactly, your errors, since I don't have your entire pom. But I would suggest you fix the dependency conflict by:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.3</version>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
          <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
           <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
           <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
         </exclusion>
     </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

Now you jackon-bind wil miss "jackson-core" and jackson-annotation, but you could add them to the pom with the proper version (2.7.3) and apply the exclusion trick.

Comment: I tried the exclusion tags, it is still failing with the error:

Comment: Your pom contains refers to a parent pom, which is not included in question description, so it's hard to replicate your case.
Jackson is really widely use library, so I doubt there is anything wrong with that. I will point to miss configuration in your repositories.

is http://scala-tools.org/repo-releases  repository down, for some reasons? 
Central repo is not necessary to defined:
http://download.java.net/maven/2/ it could be safety removed.
Is https://repository.cloudera.com/artifactory/cloudera-repos repository really need it?
Try to clean up your repository sections.